# Back-off restarting failed container with no information in events or logs

Tags: kubernetes, logging, crash, containers, kustomize

With the following kustomize:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    service: postfix
  name: postfix
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      service: postfix
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        service: postfix
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postfix
        image: fk-postfix-placeholder
        command: ["postfix"]
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
          - name: SMTP_DOMAIN
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: my-environment-config
                key: SMTP_DOMAIN
          - name: SMTP_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: my-environment-config
                key: SMTP_USER
          - name: SMTP_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: my-environment-config
                key: SMTP_PASSWORD
        ports:
        - containerPort: 25
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 1m
            memory: 50Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath:  /var/lib/postfix
          name: my-storage
          subPath: postfix
        - mountPath: /dev/shm
          name: dshm

      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: my-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: my-storage-claim-postfix
      - name: dshm
        emptyDir:
          medium: Memory
```

My pod does not come up:

```
$k get pods

NAME                          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
...
postfix-5555558c74-2kcv5      0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   16         18m
...
```

When I inspect it, I see the following in events

```
$k describe pods/postfix-5555558c74-2kcv5
...
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  28m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned my-test/postfix-5555558c74-2kcv5 to gke-xxxxxxxxx-us-central1-default-pool-xxxxxx61-29fq
  Normal   Pulled     28m (x2 over 28m)     kubelet            Successfully pulled image "registry.gitlab.com/octomy/postfix:1.0.0-test-development"
  Normal   Pulling    27m (x3 over 28m)     kubelet            Pulling image "registry.gitlab.com/octomy/postfix:1.0.0-test-development"
  Normal   Created    27m (x3 over 28m)     kubelet            Created container postfix
  Normal   Started    27m (x3 over 28m)     kubelet            Started container postfix
  Warning  BackOff    3m8s (x125 over 28m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

But when I try to figure out what happened in logs, this is what I see:

```
$k logs pods/postfix-5555558c74-2kcv5
```

Yes literally nothing is the content of the logs. When I run this in a local container using docker-compose the log is chock full of output.

So I want to know, what should be my next step in debuggin this?

Comment: did the solution of Sahadat Hossain help you?

Comment: Nope, I found the kind of obvious solution. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is obvious once you spot it. The important part is; *what does it mean when a normally log-happy container exits without a single line of log output?*

The answer is, when a chatty container does not output any logs, *the container does not start at all*. This could have many causes, but in my case the reason was that I specified a custom `command` like so:

```
command: ["postfix"]
```

There is no executable inside the container called "postfix" and so the the container simply terminated silently with exit code 1.

The reason why I had set a `command` in the first place was that I misunderstood the nomenclaturic differences between Docker and Kubernetes;

In **Docker** an `endpoint` is the executable to run and `command` is whatever arguments you pass to it. Both can be specified inside the image itself and both can be overridden at run time (for example on the commandline or in `docker-compose.yaml`).

In **Kubernetes** a `command` is the executable to run and `args` are the arguments you pass to it.

I wanted to override the Command specified inside the Docer container so I naively put `command: ["postfix"]` in my kubernetes yaml but of course in kubernetes this would override the executable rather than the arguments. The fix was to put `args: ["postfix"]` instead.

<rant>

IMHO I think this is an area of potential improvement on the part of kubernetes tools. There should at least be some kind of warning "command specified does not seem to exist in container" in the event log or appended to the empty log output.

</rant>